# Serializing dictionary for appending to json Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I want to serialize a dictionary then append it to a json. The dictionary would look something like this:   `{'weather': [], 'chat': [{'chat': 'chat'}], 'food': []}`. I need to then append it to a file. I know how to append, I just need assistance with the serializing of the dictionary. When I use `json.dumps(data)`, I gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Milo/Documents/JoeAITest.py", line 38, in <module>
print(json.dumps(data))
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

When I try and print `data`, it prints: `{'weather': [], 'chat': [{'chat': 'chat'}, {...}], 'food': []}`. If you have any questions, please leave a comment. If you have an answer, leave it in the answer section, as so many people leave it in the comments.
Thanks!

-User 9297446

Comment: Is this your exact dictionary? I can't replicate your error with `data = {'weather': [], 'chat': [{'chat': 'chat'}], 'food': []}

json.dumps(data)`

Comment: It could be `data = {'weather': [], 'chat': [{'chat': 'we need to talk'}], 'food': []}` or `data = {'weather': ['weather': 'whats the weather'], 'chat': [], 'food': []}` or something to that effect.

Comment: Your first example has no errors in `json.dumps()` and your second one is invalid (you can't use a key-val pair in an array like `[ key: val ]`. Please `print()` the exact structure that's causing the crash and post it.

Comment: `{...}` is a `set` which is not serializable

Comment: `{...}` is your issue. This could be something like: `data = {}  data['key'] = data` which is circular. Post your original code and someone will show you how to remove this reference, but it's all guesswork without your code.

Comment: remove `{...}`: `data["chat"] = {'chat':'chat'}`